# ¿Se puede asignar el valor de una constante como nombre de una cookie en PHP?

Tags: php, configuración

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
define('COOKIEOUT', 'MyCookie');

setcookie(COOKIEOUT, 'test', time() + (86400* 7), '/', 'domain.com', true, true);
```

He intentado pero lo que obtengo es un error de índice no definido en la línea donde se ajusta la cookie.

La idea de hacer esto sería la de tener un archivo PHP de configuración y mediante `include` obtener configuraciones.

En este caso sería si se quisiera cambiar el nombre de la cookie, para hacerlo simplemente en el archivo PHP a incluir, por lo que afectaría a todas las cookies en las cuales se defina el nombre obtenido de la constante.

SOLUCIONADO:

reemplace

```
setcookie(COOKIEOUT, 'test', time() + (86400* 7), '/', 'domain.com', true, true);
```

por

```
setcookie(COOKIEOUT, test, time() + (86400 * 7), '/'); // 86400 = 1 day
```

el tema del include no suelo utilizarlo hasta que las pruebas salgan bien, es decir, las constantes a exportar estan en el mismo archivo, una vez que funciona las exporto a un archivo diferente y realizo el include/require respectivo.

Comment: A mi tu código me funciona, únicamente le he quitado los parámetros a partir del cuarto, es decir, al setear la cookie, sólo le indico el nombre, el valor y la duración, y con eso en localhost me ha generado la cookie, y luego con un echo he podido ver su valor...

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que has incluido el primer archivo de configuración haciendo un [`require/require_once`](http://php.net/require_once) o [`include/include_once`](http://php.net/include_once) en el segundo?